# Android textview troubles in one page

Tags: android, textview

Hy everyone,
i have got a lot of text to diplay in one page, but i saw only first textview, other disapiard. Where is other textrview?
Code,  i dont know why i see only first texttt and a lot offf blank page. And that isall:

```
   <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <LinearLayout


            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="texttttttttt"
                android:id="@+id/textView" style="@style/MetricPrefixTitle"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="texttttttttt"
                android:id="@+id/textView1" />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Valute"
                android:id="@+id/textView" style="@style/MetricPrefixHeader"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="textttttttttttttt"
                android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="text"
                android:id="@+id/textView" style="@style/MetricPrefixHeader"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="textttttttttttttttttt"
                android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_gravity="center"/>



</LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set `android:orientation` attr in LinearLayout, the default one is horizontally so your textViews are positioned next to each other, if you scroll your text view from left to right you will see the other ones. What you want is to set `android:orientation`  to `vertical`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the orientation, your `layout_height-"match_parent"` will cause your view to expand to the size the parent allows. You should use `layout_height="wrap_content"` when you want the view height to be the height of the contents.